# Nested Div when created using width and height in percentage not working as desired

Tags: jquery, html, css

This code is supposed to cover the entire page but in turn it is covering very less part of it.

The header contains 3 sub-divs for LOGO, WEBSITE NAME and LOGOUT option respectively

The middle contains 2 sub-divs for LEFT PANEL and MAIN_CONTENT(This contains the JQuery Slideshow)

The footer should fixed to the bottom of the page.

But all the divs are getting populated on in the upper part of the webpage.

Please help me to understand what i am doing wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Photographers' Shack</title> 

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.corner.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cycle2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.slideshow').cycle({
                fx: 'fade',
                delay: -10000
            });
        });

        //$('#header').corner("bite keep 25px cc:#009");
        $('#header').corner();

    </script>

    <style type="text/css">     
        .slideshow 
        {
            height: auto; 
            width: auto;
            margin:inherit;
        }

        .slideshow img
        {
            padding: 15px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            background-color: #eee;
            height:inherit;
            width:inherit;
        }       

        @font-face
        {
            font-family: myFirstFont;
            src: url(BubblegumSans-Regular.ttf);
        }

        #header
        {
            width: 100%;
            height: 15%;
            font-family: myFirstFont;
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#003399, #335CAD, #CCD6EB, #335CAD, #003399); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
            background: -o-linear-gradient(#003399, #335CAD, #CCD6EB, #335CAD, #003399); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(#003399, #335CAD, #CCD6EB, #335CAD, #003399); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
            background: linear-gradient(#003399, #335CAD, #CCD6EB, #335CAD, #003399); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
        }

        #logo
        {
            width: 9%;
            height: 99%;
            float: left;
            text-align:center;
            border: 1px solid red;
        }

        #websiteName
        {
            width: 69%;
            height: 99%;
            text-align:center;
            display: inline-block;
            border: 1px solid red;
        }

        #otherOptions
        {
            width: 19%;         
            height: 99%;
            float: right;
            text-align:center;
            border: 1px solid red;
        }

        #middle
        {
            height:75%;
            width:100%;
            text-align:center;
        }

        #leftPanel
        {
            width: 20%;
            height: 100%;
            float: left;
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#003399, #335CAD, #CCD6EB, #335CAD, #003399); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
            background: -o-linear-gradient(#003399, #335CAD, #CCD6EB, #335CAD, #003399); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(#003399, #335CAD, #CCD6EB, #335CAD, #003399); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
            background: linear-gradient(#003399, #335CAD, #CCD6EB, #335CAD, #003399); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
        }

        #mainPage
        {
            width: 80%;
            height: 100%;
            float: right;
        }

        #footer
        {
            width: 100%;
            height: 15%;
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#003399, #335CAD, #CCD6EB, #335CAD, #003399); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
            background: -o-linear-gradient(#003399, #335CAD, #CCD6EB, #335CAD, #003399); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(#003399, #335CAD, #CCD6EB, #335CAD, #003399); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
            background: linear-gradient(#003399, #335CAD, #CCD6EB, #335CAD, #003399); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="logo">
            <table align="center"><tr><td><img src="manchester-united-logo.png"/></td></tr></table>
        </div>

        <div id="otherOptions">
            <table align="center" cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="0px"><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td><h4>Logout</h4></td></tr></table>
        </div>

        <div id="websiteName">
            <table align="center"><tr><td><h1>Photographers' Shack</h1></td></tr></table>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="middle">
        <div id="leftPanel">

        </div>
        <div id="mainPage">
            <div class="slideshow">
                <img src="images/Beetle.JPG"/>
                <img src="images/Blister Beetle.JPG"/>
                <img src="images/Cicada.JPG"/>
                <img src="images/Crab spider.JPG"/>
                <img src="images/Dragonfly1.JPG"/>
                <img src="images/Grasshopper_Nymph.JPG"/>
                <img src="images/IMG_4196.JPG"/>
                <img src="images/IMG_4248.JPG"/>
                <img src="images/IMG_4261.JPG"/>
                <img src="images/IMG_5042.JPG"/>
                <img src="images/IMG_5248.JPG"/>
                <img src="images/pellucid hawk moth.JPG"/>
                <img src="images/Rice Swift Butterfly.JPG"/>
                <img src="images/Snout Weevils Mating.JPG"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        <h6>©2013 All Rights Reserved.  •  Design by Abhijeet Kharkar</h6>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Clear your floats ("both") afterwards: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear

I assume you would do this in the "#middle" section:

```
#middle {
    clear:both;
    height:75%;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
```